# error swift 0_pthread_kill

Tags: swift

Boa tarde amigos.

estou tentando fazer um SELECT do COREDATA pois estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> 2016-01-29 13:08:39.648 epicGames[2049:1579473] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity
>   name 'wordEasy''
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecee795 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000110a77deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreData
>
>   0x000000010e4f3caa -[NSFetchRequest(_NSInternalMethods)
>   _resolveEntityWithContext:] + 426     3   CoreData                            0x000000010e4f2896 -[NSManagedObjectContext
>   executeFetchRequest:error:] + 150     4   epicGames
>
>   0x000000010e3e7838
>   _TFFC9epicGames11jogoDaForca18CaptureMensageJsonFS0_FT_T_U_FTGSqCSo6NSData_GSqCSo13NSURLResponse_GSqCSo7NSError__T_
>   + 4712    5   epicGames                           0x000000010e3e7c4a _TTRXFo_oGSqCSo6NSData_oGSqCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSqCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSqS__dGSqS0__dGSqS1___dT**
>   + 90  6   CFNetwork                           0x0000000111ca8a41 **75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke +
>   19    7   CFNetwork                           0x0000000111cbad96
>   __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 302  8   Foundation                          0x000000010f166cec
>   __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7    9   Foundation                          0x000000010f0a1e35 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101   10  Foundation
>   0x000000010f084dc5 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 646     11 
>   Foundation                          0x000000010f0849d6
>   __NSOQSchedule_f + 194    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001124483eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8     13  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000011242e82c _dispatch_queue_drain + 2215   14  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000011242dd4d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 601   15  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000112430996 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1420  16 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112430405
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011279c68f _pthread_wqthread + 1129     18 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011279a365 start_wqthread
>   + 13 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

> reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for
>   entity name 'wordEasy''

Isso quer dizer que não foi encontrado a Entidade com o nome `wordEasy` no seu .xdatamodel

Você pode tentar conferir algumas possíveis fontes desse erro:

• *Imprimir todas os nomes das entidades que você tem:*

```
let entities = managedObjectModel.entitiesByName
print("entidades: \(entities.allKeys)")
```

• *Verificar se está carregando o modelo correto, pois após atualizar o modelo com novas entidades talvez ainda esteja carregando o modelo antigo*

• *Conferir se o `Target Membership` do arquivo xcdatamodel está direcionando para o target do seu projeto*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: nossa infelizmente o problema ainda nao resolveu o que sera que pode ser?